# How to loop through corresponding columns in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a python script which reads through all the .csv files in a folder. Every .csv file contains 94 columns. I would like to loop through all the files and headers in such a way that it looks at the first column of each header, plots a single histogram containing the data from all of those first columns, then moves on to plot another single histogram containing only the data from the 2nd column, then moves on to plot another single histogram containing only the data from the 3rd column, and so on. Thus, in total it should produce 94 histograms.

I currently have code which loops a bit differently: it goes to the first file, then plots a histogram for each header in that file, then moves on to the next file, plots a histogram for each header in that file etc. Below is part of the code that does that.

```
dfs = []
for iteration, file in enumerate(files):
    _dfs = pd.read_csv(file)
    dfs.append(_dfs)
    print('Data is', round(100*((iteration+1)/len(files)), 0), '% loaded') #Prints how much data has been loaded so far.


'''-----------------------------------
Plotting Graphs
--------------------------------------
'''
for i in range(len(dfs)): #loops through files
    for k in dfs[i]: #loops through column headers
        plt.hist(dfs[i][k], 25)
        plt.title(files[i][22:]) #uses filename as title
        plt.xlabel(dfs[i][k].name) #uses column header for x-label
        plt.ylabel('Frequency Density')
        plt.show()
```

`dfs` is simply a list containing all the names of the files. How can I alter my script to achieve what I said in the beginning?

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly? You want a single loop that will open the file and plot it into a common histogram?

Comment: @drum I want to write a script which will open the first file in the list, then take the data from the FIRST column and plots a histogram, then it opens the second file in the list, and takes the data from the FIRST column and plots it onto the same histogram. It should do this for every file in the list. Then it goes back to the first file, takes the data from the SECOND column, plots it on a new histogram, then goes to the second file, takes the data from the SECOND column and plots it onto this new histogram, etc. Since each file has 94 columns, there should be 94 histograms total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

94 histograms, each histogram represents a per-column aggregation of data from all dataframes.

```
#######################
### Plotting Graphs ###
#######################

for i in range(94):
    data = [] # store all i'th column data across all dfs
    for df in dfs:
        data.extend(list(df.iloc[:,i])) # i'th column
    
    plt.hist(data, bins=25)
    plt.title(dfs[0].iloc[:,i].name) # get name of column from 1st df
    plt.xlabel(dfs[0].iloc[:,i].name) # get name of column from 1st df
    plt.ylabel('Frequency Density')
    plt.show()
```